# Manually 'approve' sub-orchestrator retry (Azure Durable Functions)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, orchestration

I am building an order processing system using Azure Durable Functions to process incoming orders step by step. This process consists of executing multiple sub-orchestrations handled by one "main" Orchestrator.

*I have simplified the example below to stay to the point*

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(RunMainOrchestrator))]
public async Task<ProcessedOrder> RunMainOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var customerOrder = context.GetInput<CustomerOrder>();

    var processedOrder = new ProcessedOrder
    {
        Id = customerOrder.TransactionId,
        customerOrder = customerOrder,
    };

    // Step 0: Create an initial record in the database
    var incomingOrder = await context.CallActivityAsync<ProcessedOrder>("StoreBaseOrder", processedOrder);

    // Step 1 of the order processing 
    var step1Result = await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<ProcessedOrder>("SubOrchestrator_1", incomingOrder);

    // Step 2 of the order processing 
    var step2Result = await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync"SubOrchestrator_2", step1Result);

    // [Do more steps]

    // Order processing finished

    return processedOrder;
}
```

There are situations where something goes wrong in one of the sub-orchestrations. An employee should take a look and manually approve a retry or termination.

**Current solution**

If something goes wrong, the sub-orchestrator waits on an external event (the manual approval):

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(SubOrchestrator_1))]
public async Task<ProcessedOrder> SubOrchestrator_1([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // (...)

    var input = new { Input = "Example" };
    var processedResult = await context.CallActivityAsync<ProcessedOrder>("DoSomething", input);

    if (processedResult.HasFailed)
    {
        // (...)

        // Wait on an employee to investigate the issue
        await context.WaitForExternalEvent("EmployeeApproval");

        // I have to return the result instead of null. 
        // If I don't, the main orchestrator gets issues with chaining the result to the next sub-orchestrator.
        return processedResult;
    }

    // Processing succesful.
    return processedResult;
}
```

In the meantime, an employee looks at the error, fixed it and triggers an HTTP call to raise the "EmployeeApproval" event. This event receives the `InstanceId` of the sub-orchestrator that failed so it can be restarted.

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(EmployeeApprovalReceived))]
public async Task EmployeeApprovalReceived(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "order-processer/approve-proceeding")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client
)
{
    var approval = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<EmployeeApproval>();

    // First raise the event to the sub-orchestrator to stop waiting
    await client.RaiseEventAsync(approval.SubOrchestratorInstanceId, "EmployeeApproval");

    // Restart the sub-orchestrator with a new instance to keep track of previous attempts.
    await client.RestartAsync(approval.SubOrchestratorInstanceId, restartWithNewInstanceId: true);
}
```

As you can see, I first raise the event *before* I restart the Sub Orchestrator. This is because the return statement **must** be executed before any restart can happen. Otherwise, an exception is thrown stating that the instance cannot be in a **running** state.

**The problem**

From the moment that the event is raised, the sub-orchestrator 'completes'. The consequence is that the **main** orchestrator continues with the **next** sub-orchestrator. Now, this seems normal because the sub-orchestrator has "finished". But actually it has failed. The next sub-orchestrator will fail because of the returned `null` from the previous one.

The restart works of the failed sub-orchestrator works fine, but has no value because the **next** sub-orchestrator already fired.

I want to prevent it from going to the next sub-orchestrator, but I can't use the build-in Retry mechanism, because I need to approve the retry first.

---

**The question**

How can prevent the main orchestrator from continuing until the failed sub-orchestrator has finished its retry? What is considered "best practice" in terms of Durable Functions?

Comment: Is there a reason a loop is not used within the sub-orchestrator (e.g. `do { } while(retry == true)`)? It could listen to both retry and terminate events simultaneously and set the flag based on which event triggers.

Comment: @juunas Do you mean that you would put all the content of the sub-orchestrator inside the `do { }` part and that `retry` value comes from the external event?

Comment: Yeah, thinking it could simplify this.

Comment: @juunas Sounds interesting. I have changed the second code sample a bit to add some more details of the context I am working in (I wanted to keep it simple ;-)). Do you still think a do/while is a possible solution here? Do I still add all content inside the do-part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work.
Using a loop, we can retry the tasks while approval is given.
I also added an example of waiting for two events and seeing which one was received.
Note this code has not been tested :)

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(SubOrchestrator_1))]
public async Task<ProcessedOrder> SubOrchestrator_1([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var retry = false;
    ProcessedOrder processedResult;
    do
    {
        // (...)

        var input = new { Input = "Example" };
        processedResult = await context.CallActivityAsync<ProcessedOrder>("DoSomething", input);

        if (processedResult.HasFailed)
        {
            // (...)

            // Wait on an employee to investigate the issue
            var approvalTask = context.WaitForExternalEvent("EmployeeApproval");
            var terminateTask = context.WaitForExternalEvent("EmployeeTerminate");
            var winnerTask = await Task.WhenAny(approvalTask, terminateTask);

            if (winnerTask == terminateTask)
            {
                // Return something to main orchestrator that indicates termination
                return terminatedResult;
            }
            
            retry = true;
        }
    } while (retry);
    
    // Processing succesful.
    return processedResult;
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean! Very clever :) But it *does* result in some warnings: https://i.imgur.com/avpYqnk.png I don't see why straight away and the amount of warnings changes. I have not had one of these warnings before. Note: this happend just after starting the orchestrator.

Comment: It seems to be fixed by itself somehow... One question though: what if I want to manually change the input (because it might be broken) inside the Table Storage, how do I get the newest version inside the sub-orchestrator? If I change it, the `context.GetInput<T>()` keeps returning the original input. I think thats 'normal' because the sub-orchestrator itself has not been initiated again by the main one.

Comment: Hmm... I feel editing the inputs through Table Storage will be a bad idea :\ You'll at least take a dependency on the serialization format that they've chosen to take. I'm not 100% sure on if the input is actually read from the history table or the control queue message that starts the orchestrator.

Comment: Good point. I just need to keep in in mind that this instance will keep running until resolved. Your solution is working for me, so I am happy :) Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!